# I am puzzled by a sentence from a game related article

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I'm not sure about the bolded sentence,

> "Until we have hard data that the presence of loot boxes in a given title is negatively affecting sales and profitability, rather than just being a thing people talk about on the internet, we should not worry about messaging issues."
>
> "That's hard to quantify but it's clearly an issue as it's getting coverage. **Whether it's an issue for most or even the majority is not as relevant as it being a big issue for some I suppose.**
>
> "The reactions to them seem to be based largely on how they are handled and whether the contents are game changing or just cosmetic."

from [this article](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/2017-10-18-loot-boxes-combat-rising-development-and-marketing-costs)

Does "some" refer to the same meaning with the "most" and "the majority", indicating the size of a group of people? And in this context, does this sentence mean that this issue is not as important(or urgent) for the most or the majority of people than it is for only a small portion("some") of the people?

Or it means that the speaker is only implying that whether this issue is hot or not, it is, to the speaker himself, not that important?

I know this maybe complicated, for I'm not sure what this means, and I'm not making myself totally clear. And simply telling me what you're thinking of this sentence will do.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is discussing the relative importance of two questions regarding some defect in the game.

1. Is it an issue for the majority of people?
2. Is it a Big Issue (ie so bad that it makes the product unusable) for some people?

The writer of the sentence is saying that in his opinion, question 1 is less important than question 2. That is to say, if the defect is a major issue for a smaller number of people, this is more important than the question of whether the majority of people find it an issue at all.

Comment: Hi Ian,i'm still a little confused....how can a defect be a showstopper at the same time? Isn't a showstopper something good?

Comment: No. Showstopper is something that stops the show. E.g. not acceptable.

Comment: Thank you both Ian and mplugjan, i'm translating this whole article into Chinese as my assignment, you're helping a lot!

Comment: @Fuze Sorry for using jargon. In software development, a showstopper is a defect which is so bad that it makes the product unusable. I will reword my answer to remove the reference.

Comment: Showstopper can be used in a positive (eg "a piece in a stage performance that the audience enjoy so much that their clapping and shouts of approval interrupt the performance", https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/showstopper)  or negative sense, generally, but in this context (software development) it's negative.